# C - Create const char* from char[]

Tags: c, mysql-connector-c

This seems simple but I'm new to C and can't find anyone asking this online. I have a `char[]` that I set with `sprintf`. Then I need to make a `const char*` from that `char[]`.  Is that possible or do I need to play around with my types?  I need a `const char*` to enter into a MySQL query, but I need the `char[]` because I need to use `sprintf` to insert variable values into the result.  Here is the code snippet:

```
char sqlbuff[4096];
const char* sqlquery;
sprintf(sqlbuff, " %s %s ",
        "SELECT idnum FROM idTbl WHERE idCol =", idVar);

sqlquery = &sqlbuff;

if ( mysql_query(con, sqlquery) ) 
{
    finish_with_error(con);
}
```

I've tried setting the `const char` variable in multiple ways, but I always get an error.  If I hardcode a value for `idVar` and simply run

```
mysql_query(con, "SELECT idnum FROM idTbl WHERE idCol = 1300)
```

it works fine.  The problem is I need to use `sprintf` to utilize the variable.  All help is appreciated.

Edit: Running on *HP-UX 11.11*

Comment: Did you try simply `if (mysql_query(con, sqlbuff))`? Arrays in C readily decay into pointers with no effort at all. BTW, beware of [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Character arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. I.e. using plain `sqlbuff` is the same as `&sqlbuff[0]`, and is of type `char *`. And a pointer to something can be implicitly used as a pointer to a `const` something. That is, a `char *` can be used when a `const char *` is expected. Lastly, the type of `&sqlbuff` is `char (*)[4096]`, and pointers to arrays like that are almost never needed.

Comment: Yes, I tried that originally.  I get a "Memory fault(coredump)" when I do that.  I'm running this on HP-UX which I'll add to the OP.  Idk if that is a factor.

Comment: @user3813942 please don't change parts of your code you already got answers for, I rolled back that change, as it would invalidate the answers. And about your "memory fault", it's most likely not a matter of the OS used and it isn't in the part of code you show. What is `idVar`? It might have the wrong type for `%s` or you might overflow your buffer .... impossible to tell from that code snippet

Comment: BTW, you could have avoided this, being aware of the ["XY problem" issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your real problem is that your program crashes. You **think** it has to do with `const char*` (it doesn't), but instead of asking about your actual problem, you asked about what you thought would be the solution. Well, if you don't find the issue, just ask a new question and include a [mcve] :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to make a `const char*` from that `char[]`

From your code sample, it seems that what you mean is that you want a `const char *` that points to the contents of your `char[]`.  That's devastatingly easy:

```
sqlquery = sqlbuff;
```

This is because values of array type are automatically converted to pointers in almost all expression contexts, and because it is allowed to assign a value of non-`const` type to a variable of the corresponding `const`-qualified type.

Moreover, for what you show, you don't even need the variable.  You can just specify the identifier of the array as the argument to `mysql_query`.  The same automatic conversion from array to pointer applies here, and you can reasonably interpret the `const` qualifier in the type of its second argument as a promise that that function will not try to modify the pointed-to data.:

```
mysql_query(con, sqlbuf);
```

On the other hand, your attempt,

```
sqlquery = &sqlbuff;  // wrong
```

, generates a pointer of the wrong type.  `&sqlbuf` is a pointer *to an array*, whereas `sqlquery` is declared to be a pointer *to a char*.  A pointer to the first `char` of a `char[]` will point to the same place as a pointer to the whole array, but the two have different types.

Comment: I don't know if it's HP-UX or the MySQL connector but I get an error when I try that.  "Memory fault(coredump)" is all it says.  Sounds like it's a unique problem though, as your answer explains the const char* should be satisfied with just passing my char[] variable.

Comment: @user3813942 it's a very bad idea to think the environment / OS is at fault when your program crashes. in 99.999% of all cases, it's your program's fault.

Comment: @user3813942, such an error as you describe arises from bad data or incorrect use of the data.  Overrunning the bounds of the array is one possibility.  Using your pointer after the end of the lifetime of the thing it points to is another.  But this would be the subject of a different question.

Comment: @user3813942: What is the type of `idVar`?  If it's an integer, then that would explain the crash - you would need to use `%d` instead of `%s`.

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong:

```
sqlquery = &sqlbuff;
```

`sqlbuff` has type `char []`, so taking its address gives you a *pointer to array*, type `char (*)[]`. You just want a pointer to the first `char` (type `char *`), and evaluating the identifier of an array results in such a pointer in most contexts (there are some exceptions like when used with `sizeof`). So, just write

```
sqlquery = sqlbuff;
```

That said, there's no need to have a separate pointer variable at all. `sqlbuff` evaluates to `char *`, and a pointer is convertable to its `const`-qualified  counterpart implicitly. Just pass `sqlbuff` directly where a `const char *` is expected and it will work.

---

Another thing should be mentioned although not directly related to your question: You should **never construct SQL queries from user input using string operations**. Attackers can easily inject own SQL code this way. Read the documentation of your SQL client library and look for *prepared statements* and *parameter binding* and use this everywhere user input needs to be a parameter in a SQL query.

---

And one more hint: If you find yourself writing code like

```
sprintf("%s", "foobar");
```

e.g., you're giving a constant string for a `%s` conversion, you're doing it wrong. Just make your constant string part of your format-string.